# Cant convert string to datetime Pandas to_datetime() out of time error

Tags: python, pandas

Error message: `OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-05-22 00:00:00`

Given dataframe

| Date | Value |
| --- | --- |
| May 22 | 1K |
| Apr 22 | 2K |
| ... | ... |
| Jan 00 | 10K |

I have tried convert it to string and called the `to_datetime()`

```python
    df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(str)
    df['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

My goal is to convert Date to datetime `05-2022, 04-2022, ... 01-2000`

Answer (score 1):

You can manually specify `format` argument of `pd.to_datetime`

```py
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%b %y')
```

```
print(df)

        Date Value
0 2022-05-01    1K
1 2022-04-01    2K
2 2000-01-01   10K

print(df['Date'].dt.strftime('%m-%Y'))

      Date Value
0  05-2022    1K
1  04-2022    2K
2  01-2000   10K
```